# How to assign / convert pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, gsoap

Please give some advice on pointers and conversion and assignment of values.

I have this fix class definition: (generated by gsoap)

```
class LibClass
{
public:
    std::string *email;    // pointer 
    int landId;                // no pointer
    // (....) much more
}
```

In a seperate function I assign data from a database (informix) to the class members above.

```
(...) // just database connection
// The following is informix interface related stuff
ITRow *row;
// define one time this conversions interface
ITConversions *c;
// placeholder for all string types, temporary data container
ITString its("");
ITString colname;

// read result from executed query 
while ( row = query.NextRow() ) {
    LibClass *ki = new LibClass;

     ki->email      = new (string);
     //ki->landId   = new (int);       // obviously : error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

    // I tried : 
    // invent a new instance 
    LibClass rki;

     //rki = &ki;
     //rki.x        = 9;

     // this is okay but how to bring ki and rki together,
     int *a = new int;
     rki.x          = *a;

    // And for understanding, here's what comes next -  It seams as i have to hardcode all 30 DB fields... but thats okay for now.

    colname="email";
    ITValue *v = row->Column( colname );
    v->QueryInterface(ITConversionsIID, (void **) &c);
    c->ConvertTo( its );
    *( ki->email ) = string(its.Data());                   // THE DATA TRANSFER - assignment
    v->Release();

   } // while end
```

**edit** I couldn't continue with this so i cannot approve the suggestions but just want to close here and so i accept the most detailled answer. thx all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a `std::string *` in `LibClass` instead of just `std::string`?

Comment: How about just `ki->landId = 0;`

Comment: @Jared , that is generated by gsoap, no idea why, i guess i have no influence on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, LibClass should not have a pointer to a `std::string` unless there is a good reason.  `std::string` internally handles all of the allocation for you.

```
class LibClass
{
public:
    std::string email;         // shouldn't be a pointer 
    int landId;                // no pointer
    // (....) much more
}
```

And then inside your `while` loop, there is no longer a need to initialize `email`, and you can just assign the value you want to `landId`:

```
LibClass ki;
// ki.email is initialized to "" already
ki.landId = 9;

// ... other code ....
ki.email = string(its.Data());
```

Or, if LibClass *must* be a heap allocated for some reason (i.e. you need to pass it out of your function):

```
LibClass *ki = new LibClass();
// ki->email is initialized to "" already
ki->landId = 9;

// ... other code ....
ki->email = string(its.Data());

// IMPORTANT: somewhere else in your program you muse delete the allocated space
delete ki;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sort of approach I'd take.

```
...
// read result from executed query 
while ( row = query.NextRow() ) {
    LibClass *ki = new LibClass;

     ki->email      = new (string); //Needed to create storage
     // That's all the setup you need on your object

     //Here's what I'd do differently
     ki->email = get_column_data(ki->email, "email");
     ki->landId = get_column_data(ki->landId, "landId");
     ...
}

template <typename T> 
void get_column_data(T target, string column_name){
    //Code to grab column data based on target type and column name
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you're doing exactly with rki and ki, but you should have

```
rki = *ki // (1)
```

Instead of

```
rki = &ki // (2)
```

Line (1) dereferences a pointer to a class instance leaving you with a class instance.

Line (2) gives you a pointer to a pointer to a class instance, but rki is not of type (LibClass **)

Comment: those were just stupid tests as you might have guessed. Thx for the hint.